# Grouping of array content

Tags: php, arrays

This is the array for which I need to display results by Order ID where we display the ID once and all the items associated with it below. There are multiple items in each ID and all the orders by ID will be displayed on screen (with pagination ofcourse).. it is just the sorting which is trouble.. any help?

```
    $this->data['transactions'][] = array(

    'amount' => $result['total'],

    'firstname' => $result['firstname'],

    'lastname' => $result['lastname'],

    'id' => $result['order_id'],

    'telephone' => $result['telephone'],

    'quantity' => $result['quantity'],

    'name' => $result['name'],

    'price' => $this->currency->format($result['price'],$this->config->get('config_currency')),

    'total' => $result['total']
    );
```

I want the output to b displayed as

### Date   OrderID   CustomerName   Tele   Amount

product

product

product

Answer (score 0):

If is the problem with sorting use this :

```
$your_array = $this->data['transactions'];
$sort = array();
foreach($your_array as $k=>$v) {
    $sort['id'][$k] = $v['id'];
}

array_multisort($sort['id'], SORT_DESC, $your_array);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($your_array);
```

Comment: Hi Prasanth, Thanks for the reply. The trouble I am having is with the display of the final output which lists all the orders with same ID. Any suggestions?